# Getter for variadic template class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to have a typed getter for a variadic template class?
I.e. something like the following but which does compile:

```
template<class... T>
class A {
public:
    A(T... params) {
        _params = { params... };
    }
    T... get(const size_t index) {
        return _params.at(index);
    }
private:
    std::vector<T...> _params;
};
```

Which is then usable like:

```
A<std::string, int> foo(std::string("a"), 2);
std::string bar = foo.get(0).append("b");
int bar2 = foo.get(1) + 2;
```

Comment: What is the type of _params? If it is an array, then why don't you use the array's element type.

Comment: Because I want the getter to return the specific types given while instantiating the class - and the array's element type would be the same for all its elements, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what `std::tuple` is for.

```
auto foo = std::make_tuple(std::string("a"), 2);
std::string bar = std::get<0>(foo).append("b");
int bar2 = std::get<1>(foo) + 2;
```

Comment: @PhilLab Note the main difference: In your case, the `get` index is a runtime value while for `std::tuple` it is a compile-time constant. You could get around this by using `boost::variant` or `boost::any`, which have however different tradeoffs.

Comment: @filmor You can index a tuple at run time. It's just trickier to do.

Comment: @T.C.: Do you have a link that explains how to do this?

Comment: @MikeMB The basic idea is to generate all the `get<N>()` calls at compile time and then pick the one to call at run time based on the value. Since the returned types can be heterogeneous, you need a visitor that can accept all possible result types. Essentially, `if(n == 0) visit(get<0>(tup)); else if(n == 1) visit(get<1>(tup)); ...`, except that the calls are generated by the compiler rather than hand-written and that the search need not be linear.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the subsequent information - it is always better to rely on already existing mechanisms instead of reinventing the wheel :-)